# Message Collector doesn't start when bot DMs user to collect response

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So this is moretheless in relation to the previous question, which was answered (the previous one) The bot is no longer spitting out a lot of errors whenever somebody runs the command, and the bot successfully DMs the user the response prompt, but it seems as if the Message Collector isn't starting? The bot DMs the user, nothing spits out in Console, and that's it. You can respond to the bot all day, and it wont collect it and send it to the channel ID. Any pointers?

Here's the code I believe it may revolve around:

````
        collector.on('collect', (message, col) => {
            console.log("Collected message: " + message.content);
            counter++; ```




And here is all of the code (just in case it actually doesn't revolve around that):
``` if(message.content.toLowerCase() === '&reserveupdate') {
        
        message.author.send('**Thanks for updating us on the reserve. Please enter what you are taking from the reserve below this message:**');
        let filter = m => !m.author.bot;
        let counter = 0;
        let collector = new discord.MessageCollector(message.author, m => m.author.id, filter);
        let destination = client.channels.cache.get('my channel id');
        collector.on('collect', (message, col) => {
            console.log("Collected message: " + message.content);
            counter++;
            if(counter === 1) {
               message.author.send("**Thanks for updating us on the reserve, it is highly appreciated.**");
                collector.stop();   
            }
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be wrong on how you created your message collector.

According to [the docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/DMChannel?scrollTo=createMessageCollector), you should make it this way :

```js
const filter = m => !m.author.bot;

// If you are in an async function :
const channel = await message.author.createDM();
// Paste code here

// Otherwise :
message.author.createDM.then(channel => {
    // Paste code here
});


// Code to paste :
const collector = channel.createMessageCollector(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000 });
collector.on('collect', msg => { 
    // ...
});
```

Hope this will help you to solve your issue ! :)

Comment: So, 2 issues here. I had tried the code you gave above, but it did not work. When ever someone runs &reserveupdate, it still dms the user, but the console says:
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'createMessageCollector' of null

I then removed the 'Create' in 'createMessageCollector' and it still gives the same Type Error. I'm going to play around with it for a few minutes, see if that changes it.

Comment: Changed "cost collector" to "let collector" and now it's spitting out undefined instead of null in the Type Error

Comment: Sorry, just got back from lunch. I am going to test it now.

Comment: This worked flawlessly, thank you @tenclea now I no longer have to deal with useless messages being sent to discord channels! Answer was marked, as well answered.